# building Xamarin UWP with AppCenter fails with error "Not found PathtoPublish"

Tags: uwp, build, visual-studio-app-center

I created a Xamarin UWP app with 4 build configurations. I created a build pipeline in AppCenter. When I push to my repo, the build runs and everything is built without any errors, but in the almost last step this error occurs:

```
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:24.09
##[section]Finishing: Build UWP sln
##[section]Starting: Copy artifacts to staging folder
==============================================================================
Task         : Copy files
Description  : Copy files from a source folder to a target folder using patterns matching file paths (not folder paths)
Version      : 2.184.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files
==============================================================================
found 0 files
##[section]Finishing: Copy artifacts to staging folder
##[section]Starting: Copy symbols to staging folder
==============================================================================
Task         : Copy files
Description  : Copy files from a source folder to a target folder using patterns matching file paths (not folder paths)
Version      : 2.184.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files
==============================================================================
found 0 files
##[section]Finishing: Copy symbols to staging folder
##[section]Starting: Publish build artifacts
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish build artifacts
Description  : Publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines or a Windows file share
Version      : 1.183.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts
==============================================================================
##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: D:\a\1\a\Build
##[section]Finishing: Publish build artifacts
```

How can I fix this error? Maybe something is wrong with my build configuration, as the copy files tasks all don't copy anything.

Comment: Hi @Martin H. Can you build success in your local machine with Visual studio?

Comment: For this scenario, the better way is making a free report with [Visual Studio App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/help#accessing-app-center-free-support), and it will get quickly response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was able to build and test locally - but I always tried debug mode.

I finally found the solution: I created several build configurations as a copy of the "Release" configuration and these configurations were set to be built in App Center. I finally checked the sln and the csproj files and these files were completely mixed up. I fixed everything project by project and now it builds in App Center as well.
my learning: never trust the "create a copy of a build configuration".